# Using Spring bean value in <resources> tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We are using Spring 3.1.2 and have a String bean defined for our client-side stuff:

```
<bean name="clientVersion" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="CLIENT_VERSION" />
</bean>
```

This gets used for various things within our beans. I want to be able to use it in the `<resources>` tag to map some of our static resources. I tried this:

```
<resources mapping="/#{clientVersion}/**" location="/path/to/versioned/resources/#{clientVersion}/" />
```

It seems to work for the mapping attribute. I see this on server startup:

```
INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/CLIENT_VERSION/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2'
```

However, when I actually hit a URL under `CLIENT_VERSION`(e.g. "CLIENT_VERSION/all.js"), I see this in the logs:

```
DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/CLIENT_VERSION/all.js] are {}
DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/CLIENT_VERSION/all.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@7dad45af] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/CLIENT_VERSION/all.js] is: -1
DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [all.js] against base location: ServletContext resource [/path/to/versioned/resources/#{clientVersion}/]
DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - No matching resource found - returning 404
```

My guess is that it's trying to find the file at /path/to/versioned/resources/#{clientVersion}/all.js, and since the file is at the path /path/to/versioned/resources/CLIENT_VERSION/all.js, it doesn't find it.

Is there a way for the `location` attribute to resolve `#{clientVersion}` like the `mapping` attribute does? Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: For Spring 4.0 it works: `class path resource [path/to/versioned/resources/CLIENT_VERSION/]`

Comment: It looks like the above works for Spring 3.2.0. I guess it was some bug in 3.1.x? The solution for me will probably be just updating the version of Spring.

Comment: It would be better, since 3.1.x is EOL